# django comment framework: distinct() does not work?

Tags: django, distinct, django-comments

Running distinct() on any field of the comment model always returns all the records,

> Comment.objects.values('user').distinct()
>
> [{'user': 1}, {'user': 0}, {'user': 0}, {'user': 0}, {'user': 0},
>   {'user': 1}, {'user': 1}, {'user': 1}, {'user': 1}]
>
> Comment.objects.values('ip_address').distinct()
>
> [{'ip_address': u'127.0.0.1'},{'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'},
>   {'ip_address':u'192.168.0.180'}, {'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'},
>   {'ip_address': u'192.168.0. 180'}, {'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'},
>   {'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'}, {'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'},
>   {'ip_address': u'192.168.0.180'}]

Why is this happening? Is there a way around this? Thanks!

ps: distinct() does run very well in different types of fields of a custom model during my test. Something special about the Comments framework?

**Bit of conclusion**
Thanks everybody answering this question, combined with some reading I get conclusion as following:

1. values() influences the lookup fields in SELECT part of the final
   sql("[values() takes optional positional arguments, *fields, which
   specify field names to which the SELECT should be limited](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#values)")
2. order_by() adds its parameter to the SELECT part as well.
3. using distinct() in a look up will result the sql to look like this:

   > SELECT **DISTINCT** [fields1, fields2, fields3] FROM ... WHERE...

   and the values of the fields all together decides whether a record is unique. The fields may come from values() or order_by() functions in the lookup.
4. [So the order_by() is adding some unwanted effects when combined with distinct(), the fields specified in order_by is also take into consideration whether a record is unique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
5. Django Comment has a hidden order_by parameter by default, thus creating the whole problem. Any model has a hidden order_by when returning the qs can cause the same problem.
6. The way of solving it is by adding an empty order_by() at the end of
   the lookup, which removes the default order_by.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Comment.objects.values('user').distinct().order_by()
```

Comment: if the OP is looking for distinct user IDs, both your solutions do not work at all

Comment: @SimonKagwi And what do they return?

Comment: Hi DrTyrsa! I'm using django 1.3 and the parameter of distinct() is not documented in this version. The second command doesn't work for Comment model, but fine on a custom model(like what I've said in PS). 

But why 'values' shouldn't affect 'distinct' behavior? If you don't tell django which column's values should be used for grouping, how can it know in which way you want to treat records as unique?

Answer (score 6):

I haven't verified that this is the cause, but [`Comment`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3/django/contrib/comments/models.py#L72) model has a default ordering which influences `distinct()` method:

```
In [1]: print Comment.objects.values('ip_address').distinct().query
SELECT DISTINCT "django_comments"."ip_address", "django_comments"."submit_date" FROM "django_comments" ORDER BY "django_comments"."submit_date" ASC
```

It's a [documented feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Now, how could it be that two comments have exactly the same timestamp? I suppose you're using MySQL which doesn't support anything less than a second.

And if you want to get rid of the default ordering, just do:

```
Comment.objects.order_by().values('ip_address').distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The hidden order_by in Comment framework is the cause of all the problems. It's a very unwanted feature in this case.

Comment: @Xun: I've updated my answer to show how to get rid of the default ordering.

Comment: Ah, sorry, IO haven't seen that you've already figured that out :)

Comment: You made it rather clear, I would be more than happy if it's possible to mark both answers as "the answer" :)

Answer (score 2):

### You can wrap your query in set;

distinct() does not go well with values() as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

```
ip_sets = set(Comment.objects.order_by().values('ip_address'))
ip_list = list(set(Comment.objects.order_by().values('ip_address')))
```