# Changing an image in Django inlineformset_factory puts it to the end of the list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views, django-formtools

Supposing I am making a **"How to"** Django webapp where users make posts about **how to-** do different things like.

- **"How to"** make a rope
- **"How to"** make an earthen pot
- **"How to"** learn to ride a bike

You get the idea. I have made the post create view for this.Now when members make the post.They add additional images to the post

**Example:** **"How to"** make a rope

- This has  Post Title = How to make a rope
- Post description = "Some description"
- Post Image = Main Image

Now they have to show images step by step how the rope is made

- **Image 1**: Do this 1st
- **Image 2**: Do this 2nd

I am using Django formsets along with my post model to achieve this. Everything is working absolutely fine in create view. no problems. But in update view things break.

> The Problem

The problem is when a user wants to EDIT their post and switch image number 2. from their post to a different image. Even though they changed the 2nd image. That image now ends up at the very end of the list. Making the user to re-upload all the images. To bring back the Order. Making my app look buggy.

**Example:** Lets assume user has the below post

```
main post Title 
" Some description "
Main Image = Post_image.jpg  

1st Image = A.jpg
   Image Title
   Image description
2nd Image = B.jpg
   Image Title
   Image description
3rd Image = C.jpg
   Image Title
   Image description
4st Image = D.jpg
    Image Title
     Image description
5th Image = E.jpg
     Image Title
     Image description
6th Image = F.img
     Image Title
     Image description
```

> Now if I changed 2nd image `B.jpg` to `b.jpg`  b.jpg moves to the very end of the list and you have the order as A, C, D, E, F, b

**Below are my models:**

```
 class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True,max_length=500)
    post_image = models.ImageField()
    message = models.TextField()

class Prep (models.Model): #(Images)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post_prep')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True, default='')
    image_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    image_description = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='')
    sequence = models.SmallIntegerField() ###########################ADDED THIS

    class Meta:    ###########################ADDED THIS
    unique_together = (('post', 'sequence'),) ###########################ADDED THIS
    ordering = ['sequence']  ###########################ADDED THIS
```

**My post create view**

```
def post_create(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(Prep, fields=('image', 'image_title', 'image_description'), extra=12, max_num=12,
                                        min_num=2)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            post_user = request.user
            for index, f in enumerate(formset.cleaned_data): #######CHANGED THIS
                try: ##############CHANGED THIS
                    photo = Prep(sequence=index, post=instance, image=f['image'], 
                             image_title=f['image_title'], image_description=f['image_description'])
                    photo.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    break

            return redirect('posts:single', username=instance.user.username, slug=instance.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=Prep.objects.none())
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)
```

**My post Edit View:**

```
class PostPrepUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ('title', 'message', 'post_image')
    template_name = 'posts/post_edit.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PostPrepUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['prep'] = PrepFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['prep'] = PrepFormSet(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        prep = context['prep']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if prep.is_valid():
                prep.instance = self.object
                prep.save()
        return super(PostPrepUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

**My Forms.py**

```
class PostEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'message', 'post_image', 'group', )


class PrepForm(forms.ModelForm): #####################CHANGED THIS
    class Meta:
        model = Prep
        fields = ('image', 'image_title', 'image_description', 'sequence')


PrepFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Post, Prep, form=PrepForm, extra=5, max_num=7, min_num=2)
```

> ***Need help fixing this issue. Example if they change Image 2. Then it should stay at Number 2 position and not move to the end of the list

Comment: Have you tried apply any ordering on Prep model?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar no What you see is what I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you don't save the order of the images, relying on the fact that they are displayed in the same order as they are created. Adding a field in `Prep` containing the place of the image in the sequence of images would help:

```
class Prep (models.Model):
    # ...
    nr = SmallIntegerField()
    #...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('post', 'nr'),)
```

The `unique_together` constraint ensures that every number is only used once per post. This also allows reordering of images within a post without deleting and recreating all `Prep` objects.

On displaying the post, you'd have to order the `Prep` objects by `nr`.

---

As for populating the new column, since there's no single default value that makes sense, the easiest approach might be:

- Add the `nr` field without the `unique_together` constraint and with `null=True` first; migrate the changes.
- After migration, loop over the existing `Prep` objects of each `Post` in the current order and assign them ascending numbers.
- After that remove `null=True`, add `unique_together` and migrate again.

`unique_together` needs string parameters (it cannot access the fields in the outer class); thanks for catching that.

---

On the edit form, you'd want to include the new field so that users can swap the order of two images by swapping their indexes. You just have to provide them a meaningful error message if they use duplicate indexes.

When creating however, your users don't need to specify the order explicitly as it is implicit in the sequence of the images in the formset. So I'd suggest changing your for loop like this:

```
for index, f in enumerate(formset.cleaned_data):
    # ...
    photo = Prep(nr=index,
                 # add all other fields
                )
```

Use `nr = index + 1` for human-friendly indexes starting with 1. In fact, `index` or `image_index` might be a better name for the field than `nr`.

Comment: checking this now

Comment: just a quick question, If a already have data in my database and run makemigrations. Django usually asks `Provide a one-off default now`. Do you have any suggestions about what default I can add

Comment: Also is it `unique_together = (("post", "nr"),)`  as usually unique together is a string value or is it `((post, nr),)` without the string

Comment: Also can you give a small preview of the views.py How Do I add values in the SmallIntegerField I am adding my `CreateView` above in the question

Comment: Also you can set `order_by` in `Prep` meta to have have default ordering of the steps.

Comment: @gonczor You can, although this can [come](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#s-interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) [back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017706/django-comment-framework-distinct-does-not-work) [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54354462/django-distinct-returns-more-records-than-count) [bite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52012652/django-distinct-not-returning-distinct-values) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156661/django-aggregation-count/55158744#55158744), which is why I prefer explicit ordering where needed.

Comment: trying this now

Comment: I though this will work. I deleted all the posts and then did make migrations and migrate. I added null and then did migrate the. removed null chose `Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself` then did migrate again everything was successful. But when I change the 1st Prep image it still goes to the very end

Comment: Also changing the `nr` value in the edit form is not making any difference in the form edit. You think maybe you missed something

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Two points: 1) You need to make sure (e.g. by inspecting either the database or the objects in the Django shell) that the index is saved as expected, both when creating and when editing. If the indexes are *not* assigned and saved correctly, debug that. If they are: 2) You need to use the index at the end of the queryset) to sort the images everywhere you need it (basically when displaying and editing the post). You need `.group_by('nr')` for that. Here again, you need to debug to make sure that the querysets list the objects in the required order. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, item 2 should read: 2) You need to use the index to sort the images everywhere you need it (basically when displaying and editing the post).

Comment: I have changed my question to show the changes you suggested. Can you advise where I add `.group_by('nr')`  Only thing is `instead of "nr" I use "sequence"`

Comment: If you use `ordering` as in your posted code, you don't need `order_by` (`group_by` was an error on my part for `order_by`, apologies!).