# Django Aggregation Count

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I'm trying to filter my model with an aggregate function.

I have a Model A and a Model B with a foreign key on the model A.

```
annotate_pool = queryset.annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets')).all()
for obj in annotate_pool:
    bets_obj = obj.bets.all()
    bets_length = len(bets_obj)
    print(obj.nb_bets, bets_length)
```

And the annotation doesn't give me the same result as the function length.

```
1 1
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 1
1 1
2 2
```

Here is my models:

```
class Pronostic(models.Model):
    cote_total = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    trust = models.IntegerField()
    mise_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    safe = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Bet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    match = models.ForeignKey('pronostics.Match', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bets')
    cote = models.FloatField()
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    pronostic = models.ForeignKey('pronostics.Pronostic', related_name='bets', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`len(bets_obj)` should give me the same result as `Count('bets')`.
What is going on? Why does `Count` give me a wrong result?

Thank you in advance.

***EDIT:***

I'm using django-rest-framework, and try to add a custom filter.  ([see doc here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering)).
The result expected is: 
`obj.nb_bets` should be equal to `bets_length`. Since I want to filter my models like this:

```
queryset.annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets')).filter(nb_bets__gte=2)
```

or

```
queryset.annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets')).filter(nb_bets__lte=2)
```

Here is the SQL query contained in my queryset:

```
SELECT "pronostics_pronostic"."id",
       "pronostics_pronostic"."cote_total",
       "pronostics_pronostic"."trust",
       "pronostics_pronostic"."mise_ratio",
       "pronostics_pronostic"."safe"
FROM "pronostics_pronostic"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "pronostics_bet" 
       ON ("pronostics_pronostic"."id" = "pronostics_bet"."pronostic_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "pronostics_match" 
       ON ("pronostics_bet"."match_id" = "pronostics_match"."id")
WHERE ("pronostics_pronostic"."visible" = TRUE
       AND "pronostics_pronostic"."safe" = TRUE)
ORDER BY "pronostics_match"."date" DESC
```

If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: Could you please update models.py and what output would you require?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the case but try to remove `.all()` when creating `annotate_pool`. And see if the results are the same? just leave `queryset.annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets'))`.

Comment: No, that's not the problem :/

Comment: `queryset.annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets')).order_by('pk').values('pk', 'nb_bets')` is it?

Comment: Can you provide your queryset?

Comment: How does you define queryset, is it like this: `queryset = Pronostic.objects.all()`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I updated the question to give you more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the SQL you posted, your `Pronostic` objects are ordered by the field `date` in a related `Match` object. If you remove the ordering (using an empty `order_by()`), I would expect the numbers to match up. Test this:

```
annotate_pool = queryset.order_by().annotate(nb_bets=Count('bets')).all()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain me a bit more how the order_by change the result?
Because I still want them in the good order...
Because Dajngo rest framework tells me: 
`UnorderedObjectListWarning: Pagination may yield inconsistent results with an unordered object_list`

Comment: Well, what would be a "good order"? You can only order by a field that's in your query.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question as long as you don't show the queryset for `annotate_pool`.

My guess is that you have fields from `Bet` in your SQL query for `annotate_pool`, resulting in duplicate `Protostic`s that are only differentiated by the related `Bet` fields, which again leads to a lower bet count. Test:

```
Pronostic.objects.count() < len(annotate_pool)
```

`True` or `False`? My guess is `True` (provided that `annotate_pool` is unfiltered and contains all `Pronostic` objects). This means that you have duplicate `Pronostic`s in `annotate_pool`. The number of `Bet`s is spread out over those duplicates.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that using `queryset.distinct()` should solve this for the OP.

Comment: Nope, `distinct` works at the SQL level (not the main object level) and doesn't help if the related fields included in the SQL are unique, see [this warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

Comment: `distinct` should apply to all of the columns in the `SELECT`. If it's a many-to-many, it's not going to be included in that set of columns which would allow distinct to filter down to the unique instances.

Comment: Sorry, "duplicate" may have been confusing. I meant that the queryset containing the main objects (`Pronostic`) contains multiple `Pronostic` objects with the same primary key; the underlying query rows however are usually unique because they include fields from a joined table.

Comment: I think we're on the same page. Any differences are likely because we don't know how exactly `queryset` is defined.

Comment: Yes, that would be fun to know at last; the OP keeps the suspense up.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I updated the question to give you more information.